# Sticky menu changing color when scrolling down without jquery

Tags: angular, html, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox navigation menu in my angular 6 project , I want to change the background-color when the menu is sticky at the top .

Here is what I would like to have [sample],
[Expected result](http://en.astek.pl/)

Here is what I have so far :

[sticky menu on scroll](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bootstrap-nabar-snoyrg)

here is css for sticky menu using `position: sticky`

```
.main-nav-sticky{
  background-color: white;
}

.main-nav {
  margin-top: 100px;
  position: sticky;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  color: green;
}
```

I just want when a user scroll and the menu is sticky at the top,  the navigation the menu  should have a `background-color: white`

what am I missing in my code? am newbie just learning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Keno mentioned, the `position: inherit` in your media query is over riding `position: sticky`.

But using `position: sticky` only makes "sticky" relative to the parent not to the window according to MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

> A stickily positioned element is an element whose computed position value is sticky. It's treated as relatively positioned until its containing block crosses a specified threshold (such as setting top to value other than auto) within its flow root (or the container it scrolls within), at which point it is treated as "stuck" until meeting the opposite edge of its containing block.

For you to achieve the desired behavior the you should use `position: fixed` which is according to MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

> It is [the element] positioned relative to the initial containing block established by the viewport.

So your CSS should be

```
.main-nav-sticky {
   background-color: white;
}

.main-nav {
  margin-top: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  color: green;
}
```

And as for changing the color of the navbar when the user scrolls, you are going to **need** javascript to detect the scroll event and change the colors accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You have a media query which is interfering with the positioning on smaller screens. It is sticky until it reaches the end of its parent container.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .main-nav {
     margin: 0;
     display: block;
     /* position: inherit; This is the problem */
   }
}
```